# How to make data:{confirm..} work in rails 6 | button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

my confirm popup not working in rails 6.
I added gem 'jquery-rails' to GEMFILE and run bundle install. I also added

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

this in application.js which is linked in layouts/application.html.erb as

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Button working, and delete users, but there is not popup, where i can confirm, that i want to delete that user. What am i doing wrong?

This is my code in dashboard.html.erb

```
<%= button_to "Delete account",
                            admin_dashboard2_path(currentUser.id),
                            method: :delete,
                            data: {confirm:'Are you sure?'},
                            class: 'btn btn-primary'
          %>
```

This is code in browser:

````
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/ed-admin/39"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" /><input data-confirm="Are you sure?" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Delete account" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="WFyXCkE6r4vmcecfQF_ngWlHHU22bkKRLTT_cNeAC47szzjOd9JtuY_33L_4BUdWIcudhKRN0seWNO5QZ6MCfQ" /></form>```
````

Comment: Tip: On stackoverflow you want to use the "base" tags (`ruby-on-rails`) and not just the version tag (`ruby-on-rails-x`). The tags don't actually have a heirarcy so `ruby-on-rails-6` does not show up on the feed for `ruby-on-rails` and barely has any followers. I added the tag for you.

Comment: @Mateusz Bialowas - why do you want to use `button_to` instead of `link_to`? `button_to` isn't supposed to send GET or DELETE requests.

Comment: @NitinSrivastava i changed that to link_to and there is still no popup This is my pull request https://github.com/mateuszbialowas/Edisk-Rails/pull/4/files

Comment: @Mateusz Bialowas still `button_to` is there.

Comment: @NitinSrivastava i fixed that and record short tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZO6vzA9pmI

Answer (score 0):

You can use data-confirm-modal gem to do this,hope it will work
https://github.com/ifad/data-confirm-modal